# How to check if a directory exists and create a new one if it doesn't?

Tags: directory, rust

I tried the following but I don't think it's particularly pretty:

```
let path = "target/dir";
if !std::path::Path::new(&path).exists() {
    std::fs::create_dir(path)?;
}
```

Comment: Not only is this not pretty, it is also subject to a TOCTTOU attack. There are very few reasons why one would ever want to check if a file/directory exists like that. Shepmaster's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

[`std::fs::create_dir_all`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.create_dir_all.html):

> Recursively create a directory and all of its parent components if they are missing.
>
> #### Examples
>
> ```
> use std::fs;
>
> fs::create_dir_all("/some/dir")?;
> ```

Comment: Any idiomatic way to say "Write this text to this file, creating any ancestor directories as needed?" Best I have atm is: `fs::create_dir_all(file_path.clone().parent().unwrap())?; fs::write(file_path, file_contents)?;`

Comment: @Venryx that's about what I'd do, but avoiding the clone and the unwrap: `if let Some(p) = file_path.parent() { fs::create_dir_all(p)? }; fs::write(file_path, file_contents)?;`

Comment: This is a succinct example but the fs::create_dir_all("/some/dir")?; line does not compile.

Comment: You need to run it in a function that returns `Result<(), std::Error>`, or change the `?` for a `.expect("Failed to create")`

Comment: I don't know why but if I don't check if the directory already exists, `create_dir_all` fails.