# refer to either path

Tags: rust, directory

I have a string, which refers to Team Foundation and is being used in a few functions. However, I would like it to check whether that file (TF.exe) is located on Enterprise `(const TF: &'static str = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TeamFoundation/Team Explorer/TF.exe";)` or Professional (.../2019/Professional/...). I've read about solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48053933/how-to-check-if-a-directory-exists-and-create-a-new-one-if-it-doesnt-in-rust), however, it is not the best one. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "solution" you link to isn't even a solution to your problem, as you don't seem to be wanting to create either of those directories if they don't exist. What have you tried so far? You need to include a [mcve].

Comment: Also, do you already have both paths and simply need to check which one the file exists at, or do you have one path and need to determine which one it is?

Comment: @Herohtar I have one path and need to determine which one that is

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::path::Path::starts_with`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.starts_with) like so:

```rust
use std::path::Path;

const TF: &'static str = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TeamFoundation/Team Explorer/TF.exe";

const ENTERPRISE: &'static str = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise";
const PROFESSIONAL: &'static str = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional";

fn main() {
    let path = Path::new(TF);
    if path.starts_with(ENTERPRISE) {
        println!("{}", "enterprise")
    } else if path.starts_with(PROFESSIONAL) {
        println!("{}", "professional")
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If the string is not user-writable, you could use

```rust
let professional = str.contains("es");
```

,or any other string or substring that would only be found in the human readable word `Enterprise` or `Professional`, and nowhere else in the location, which would save a lot of memory since a lot of big strings for the `starts_with` checks could be ignored, but @Ekrim Dinçel 's answer is probably best in most circumstances